# is it possible to build a material that would render like an old print?

Tags: rendering, materials

Would it be possible to build up a material that would look like an old print (I don't know the word in english, is it "engraving" ?) ?

Just wondering.

Tell me if you got ideas on how to make this !

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Yes, this looks like metal engraving. Using *Freestyle* lines would probably be easier than setting up a whole material.

Comment: I know about freestyle, but it is far from this. Anything I could start from ?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168636/tapering-textures-with-nodes

Comment: Thanks to @Bruno's answer, I found out that, which is quite amazing ! https://blendermarket.com/products/komikaze