# Creating CMYK Printing Simulator/Shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, color-management

Out of curiosity, I wanted to see if I could develop a quick little CMYK print shader in cycles. So that I could plug different images in to the shader and have it display as if it had been physically halftone printed. Very similar to an RGB screen shader I've seen before that separated the RGB colors and put them back together as pixels/cells...

Below is the basic set up I've started with, but am curious if anyone out there has more experience with printing that could offer any advice to get something closer to a realistic result? As I'm already certain that just separating R->M G->Y B->C is not the actual correct way of doing this, just thought I'd start with that to see if it actually did anything.

[image: overview]

[image: detail1]

Would love to hear any input :)
Thanks!

Comment: I guess maybe related.. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102352/blender-halftone-pattern-filter

Comment: Compositor has a separate YCbCr node.  I dunno if that's relevant, just tossing it out there.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99409/how-to-use-halftone-python-shader-node and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175575/creating-this-halftone-effect-using-arrays and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168636/tapering-textures-with-nodes/168642#168642

Answer (score 3):

Yeah I strugged with the making a cmyk simulator to but I stumb across this tutorial on reddit by [Gwirk](https://www.reddit.com/user/Gwirk/)

[He went through the process on how to make a half-tone](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/aveb3f/cmyk_printing_pattern_for_blender_shaders_a/)

It pretty much goes like this

## Step 1: Offset each color value by -1

### generate your color negative channels

this will invert it the color and give us the cyan ,magenta ,yellow color we need

The problem now is that we have the black data mix up with the color data

[image: [node group with the r g b being subtracted by one]]

## Step 2: Grab the min value of all the color channel

### generate your K/black channel

this will be your K or black value ,and will also help in removing the black data from your color info

*K = min(R <sub>1</sub> ,G <sub>1</sub> ,B <sub>1</sub> )*
[image: [the black channel being calculated here]]

### generate your K/black negative channel:

This is the same operation as in step 1 but instead you'll be substituting color with K

K <sub>1</sub> = K - 1
[image: min key offset pic]

## Step 3: Remove the black from the color channel

### You'll have to offset the color channel by your black channel

you're just subtracting K from your colors

R <sub>2</sub>=R <sub>1</sub>- K

B <sub>2</sub>=B <sub>1</sub>- K

G <sub>2</sub>=G <sub>1</sub>- K

### Then divide by your black negative channel

R <sub>3</sub>=R <sub>2</sub>/ K<sub>1</sub>

B <sub>3</sub>=B <sub>2</sub>/ K<sub>1</sub>

### G <sub>3</sub>=G <sub>2</sub>/ K<sub>1</sub>
[image: this is the final step for part 1]
[image: completion image]

The next part is to convert it back to `rgb`

This this simpler as you’re just undoing the conversion you did in the previous section

Just multiply your color channel by a negative version of the black channel
and then add back the black channel you removed
[image: CMYK to RGB node]

> don't forget to undo the offsetting you done to each color channel
> sorry about the small image
> here's a colored aided
> [image: color aid images]

---

all that's left is to plugin halftone shader of choice.
this part is a creative step so I'm not going to describe. how to do just going to link to a bunch of halftone shader tutorials instead

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=li2mSnKY194
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vnLJmqiBDXI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjQ37vFLotk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Go8ivK00Y-A
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-1w4pYdUNQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRP1DqShceM

[image: no description]
*half - tone generator by the original poster of the tutorial on reddit*
[image: half - tone generator by the original poster of the tutorial on reddit]
[image]

down below is a article that explains everything better than I can
https://bensimonds.com/2013/02/14/halftone-shader/